# datagridview double click event

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm new to programming. I have a form (named personal_Info) that fills some person's personal data and saves it in the database table `Personal_Information`.

2nd I have another form that searches from `Personal_Information` and shows results in a grid view.

I now want: When search result show in data grid view and when I double click on any row of the shown results I want (personal_info) to open and make an edit at that form and save it.

Please help me.

here is little code which gets data from sql to grid

```
SqlConnection strconn = new SqlConnection("server=AAG-PC; Database=humanResource; Integrated Security=sspi"); 
strconn.Open(); 
SqlCommand strcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Personal_Information where "
+ searchComboBx.SelectedItem
+ " like '%" + txtBxKeyword.Text.Trim() + "%'", strconn); 
SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(strcmd); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet (); 
ad.Fill(ds); 
strconn.Close(); 
gridViewSearchResult.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: here is little code which gets data from sql to grid                      SqlConnection strconn = new SqlConnection("server=AAG-PC;Database=humanResource;Integrated Security=sspi");
            strconn.Open();
            SqlCommand strcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Personal_Information where "+searchComboBx.SelectedItem+" like '%" + txtBxKeyword.Text.Trim() + "%'", strconn);
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(strcmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
            ad.Fill(ds);
            strconn.Close();
            gridViewSearchResult.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Answer (score 1):

You can use dataadapter to update your changes. It will be something like

```
changes = ds.GetChanges();
if (changes != null)
{
     adapter.Update(changes);
}
```

you can see more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26946577/2892829)