# Update From DataGridView to Database

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim sb As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
sb.Server = Form1.hostname.Text
sb.UserID = Form1.rootuser.Text
sb.Password = Form1.rootpassword.Text
sb.Database = Form1.hostdb.Text
sb.Port = Form1.hostport.Text
Using connection As New MySqlConnection(sb.ConnectionString)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim adapter1 As New MySqlDataAdapter(TextBox1.Text, connection)
        Dim cmdb1 = New MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter1)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim words As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(New Char() {" "c})
        Dim tablenamewords = (words(3))
        adapter1.Update(ds, tablenamewords)
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connection.Dispose()
    End Try
End Using
```

It's giving me this error:

> Update unable to find TableMapping['creature_template'] or DataTable 'creature_template'.

I want to select items then use a DataGrid to update them.

Note: `tablenamewords = "creature_template"`

Comment: did you bind your datagridview to you db?

Comment: `                Dim adapter1 As New MySqlDataAdapter(InfluenceMultiLineTextBox1.Text, cn)
                Dim table As New DataTable()
                adapter1.Fill(table)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = table`

Comment: Given the similarity between C# and VB, doe any comments here apply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946397/how-to-update-sql-server-database-using-datagridview-binding-source-c-sharp?

Comment: This won't really help but since you have a `Using connection ...` you don't need `Finally ... connection.Dispose()` because the `End Using` will automatically call dispose in any event.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in alot of different methods.

I prefer to update the DB with a single query every time the the user ends editing a cell.

**BUT FIRST** you have **to bind** a source to your `DataGridView`!

***How to bind a source:***

- Go to your application design an click on your DataGridView
- Click on the `pause/start` like little button as shown:

[image: little button]

- Click on the "ComboBox" like textbox labeled as "chose data source" as shown and click on it:

[image: "Scegli origine dati means "chose data source"]

- It will open a "form", click on the `Add data source` as shown:

[image: aggiungi origine dati means "add data source"]

- Follow the wizard, you can do it without any furhter explanation!

**Well done**, you almost completed it. Just go in your code, and look for this sub:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.your_table_nameTableAdapter.Fill(Me.your_db_nameDataSet.your_table_name)
End Sub
```

The line inside your `Form1_Load` Sub will upload the data inside your `DataGridView`, leave it there if you want it to load with the form or cut/paste it wherever you like.

Now you can add this the code to programmatically update the DB:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    Try
        Dim location As Point = DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress
        Dim sqlCmd As String = "UPDATE table_name SET " & _
                                    DataGridView1.Columns(location.X).Name.Replace("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn", "") & " = @Data " & _
                                    "WHERE " & _
                                    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name.Replace("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn", "") & " = @ID"
        Using myConn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.VISURE_DA_PDFConnectionString)
            myConn.Open()
            Using myCmd As New SqlCommand(sqlCmd, myConn)
                myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                myCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
                myCmd.Parameters("@Data").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(location.Y).Cells(location.X).Value
                myCmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(location.X).Value
                myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            myConn.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Err.Clear()
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Remarks:**

- `location.X` is the col index, `location.Y` is the row index
- `DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name` This is my `ID` (primary key) and it is always in the first column. Change it with yours.
- Don't forget to add `.Replace("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn", "")` whan you are getting your column name

As previously said, this code will update your DB every time the user edits one cell on your `DataGridView` updating only the edited cell. This is not a big issue because if you want to edit two ore more cell, every time you leave an edited cell the method `DataGridView1_CellEndEdit` is fired!

Comment: This doesn't work simply because the person will be using random columns and random names so it's not something specified : Data - ID etc...

Comment: @JohnEvenetcha as I asked before, did you bind your DataGridView to your db? if Yes the col name and the order would be the same as in your table.

Comment: I'm not understanding how it is binded .. i means if it's binded than changing anything in datagridview will be also updated to database which i want i means if i know how to do that than i won't ask for it :D well i think you're not understanding my point but thx for helping at least you tried.

Comment: I'm going to edit the answer in order to help you with bindings. As far as i know, I didn't find a way to update the db also if it's binded to the datagrid. The only way is to query the update

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i4mYXSaD4w this is what i want exactly the issue there it's c# but what i want is exactly like that..

Comment: Cannot open youtube links at the moment, sorry

Comment: It's fine, just please check a solution with me i'm so stuck at this .. and thanks ;)

Comment: @JohnEvenetcha Edit done, hope you will find your way easier now ;)

Comment: Thank you very very much i'll try and tell you if works

Comment: update : well i noticed that binding to db will keep the same information for the ( server  / root / pass etc.. ) i don't want that to happen as this is sharable application everyone gonna use his database information ...  sadly the solution didn't work @Simo

Comment: rip... 8 more to go

Comment: Not just that ... but it didn't even work gives me unexpected error when selecting the table  .. well seems so stuck any other ideas please ?

Comment: @JohnEvenetcha _this is sharable application everyone gonna use his database information_
But the DB is still the same right? whan you bind a source you can select from a static connection string (always same db, same user, same password) or to login with Windows Credential! at this point just give the user the right permissions on your DB, or, use a static string but anyone will login with the same account

Comment: @JohnEvenetcha you can also create a little form where the user insert the credential to login, so you know exactly wich table he wants to use, witch DB, and you can bind it programmatically

Comment: yeah that's what it already have see this picture : http://prntscr.com/kt7uwe and this for how the datagridview will work : http://prntscr.com/kt7vg9

Comment: i was also thinking about convert DataGridView to SQL query ( REPLACE ) so it will work perfectly ;)

Comment: Nice to hear that!

Comment: Try to programmatically bind data source based on user input (create a form for the db login)

Comment: That already exists check pictures .. well i found a youtube video i'll try it it's vb.net ty in advance !